# How to create a web map which can't be traced back to yourself?

Tags: web-mapping, cloud-gis, hosting

Hypothetically speaking (of course) say that you wanted to do a Wikileaks-style exposé of some spatial data, without it being traceable back to yourself.

The data could be points, line and polygons (with attributes) in any common spatial format (shapefile, geodatabase, GeoJSON, etc).

What would be the best way to host it anonymously in an interactive web map? Where would it be hosted, and what software would you use?

You would then anonymously contact a journalist and send them the URL to your webmap (so it needs to be something interactive which a journalist could use in an online article, not just a JSON dump that only a geek could decipher).

Comment: For focussed Q&A I think you need to describe what you have tried and where you are stuck.  Otherwise I think this is an open-ended question and thus too broad. .

Answer (score 1):

Any of the web-mapping services like CartoDB, Mapbox, ArcGIS online can fit. They offer good enough free options, including iframe embedding and an option to download the spatial data. 
You have to register a user account with an email, but that's not something too difficult to do with an untracebale account.

Comment: +1 And you could use https://www.mailinator.com as the untraceable email.